# How to read or access csv file from iCloud account in iPhone which is already stored in it

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

As a programmer i want to access csv files in iphone from iCloud, which is already stored in it by user. I don't want to create or store csv file, just need to read or access available csv files in iCloud account which is stored by user.

Is it possible ? If yes then how.
Thank you in advance for your help and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is *where* is iCloud is the CSV file stored? If you didn't create it you won't be able to access it. iCloud isn't a filesystem like Dropbox. It's more like a "cloud" version of iOS, where everything is sandboxed and can only be amended by the app that created it.

If you did create it, then you access it in pretty much the same way you put it there. Check out the iCloud documentation.